# Kind of "apply" for a clamp to constraint?

Tags: constraints

I have a low-poly bridge model whose poles are positioned using *Clamp To* constraints and a corresponding curve:

[image: Bridge, Pole_01 and ArchPathRight selected]

What I am looking for is a way to remove the constraints but to keep the position of all objects at the same place it was with the active constraint. Something pretty similar to applying a modifier but for constraints.

Maybe I used just the wrong key words for searching but I haven't found any easy way to achieve this. Appears like I have to write a python script to get this done.

Anyone out there with a more elegant and simpler way to solve this?

Thanks, Kay.

**UPDATE:**

I did it the way [iKlsR](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/12/iklsr) suggested and it worked fine. If others need this for a couple of objects, too: You can select all, do the *Apply Visual Transform* at once and then choose *Clear Object Constraints* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to remove all constrains in one step.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can just apply the *Visual Transform*. *(read about this some more [on the wiki](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html?highlight=apply%20transform#visual-transform))*

Bring up the *Apply* menu with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and choose *Apply Visual Transform*, or alternatively, select the object, press <kbd>Space</kbd> and type *Apply Visual Transform* and select the option.

You can then safely delete the constraint.

Comment: BTW: Thanks for the <kbd> formatting trick. Got almost 5k rep on SO but never noticed that :-)

Comment: If "applying" only TrackTo constraint, it's possible also to clear constraint choosing *Clear And Keep Transformation* (`Alt`+`T`).

Answer (score 1):

This question now has a better answer in Blender 3.0 since you can now apply constraints like modifiers.
(see https://developer.blender.org/D10914)