# How to increase spacing between duplicated objects parented to a curve using *DupliFrame* ?

Tags: instances

I have a plane that has been duplicated along a curve:

[image: image1]

I parented the plane to the curve (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and then used *DupliFrames* on the plane to get the above scene. However, I want to increase the relative spacing between the planes. Any suggestions on that?

Please don't ask me use to *Array Modifier*/*Curve Modifier* (I know that will solve my current problem but it will also prevent my planes from staying horizontal as they are currently since they will use the normal of the curve for their orientation). Is there a way to increase the spacing under the above setup? Maybe some curve property?

Comment: No, you are perfectly correct. Thank you. I just actually figured out how to DupliFrame works. 

In this case I still need my original curve to have the same number of frames, so I can just create less number of frames copy of it. Thank you. 

[P.S. How do I mark comments as the answer ? ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to increase the spacing between all the instances evenly, that necessarily reduces their number, so reduce the number of frames in the curve's path animation panel.

Comment: Hi Robin, a follow up question on that. How do I keep the spacing so that the projection of the planes on the X axis are evenly spaced ? For e.g. if I extruded the above planes along Z-axis to look like pillars/columns, how can I keep the pillars evenly spaced with respect to the floor ? (Currently they are evenly spaced along the path of the curve, so my pillars look unevenly spaced on the floor)

[P.S. I can post as a separate question if you think its difficult to do it]

Comment: Added the question here, in case you can help me. Thank you.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106840/how-to-make-evenly-spaced-pillars-for-a-roller-coaster-track

Comment: I think that is a new question, because on SE, Q&A's should be searchable, and not private conversations.. (Someone might suggest an entirely different approach)